# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any Reason why this keeps happening even though the query is valid?... My code is below :)

```
Select Cdf_Code_Tx, ProjectNo, Convert (Date, [Last Call Back],103) As LastCallBack, (CDF_New_des1_Tx+CDF_New_des2_Tx) As Description
From Products
Inner Join SpecDetails
On CDF_Code_Tx = ProductRef
Inner Join Projects2
On ProjectNo = PID
WHERE  [Last Call Back] = (SELECT MAX(Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103))FROM Projects2)
Order By Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103)
```

When i run this , this error appears!

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Needing guidance & Thank you in advance.

Comment: & by keeps happening i mean the question is my problem :)

Comment: Kindly help us posting exact error to help you added table structure info would be cheery on cake.

Comment: It seems like `[Last Call Back]` is a varchar column that really should be a date column. What are the values there (=any non-date values)?

Comment: Error is now on the table :)

Comment: Can you check some sample data on `[Last Call Back]` column? Or you can use `ISDATE` to check the column contains correct date values

Comment: Hans , it's being converted to 'Date' and it runs fine when i don't have my Where clause in the Query but doesn't bring my last call back even with Desc/Asc

Comment: Humpty - What do you mean check the sample data on that column? i am new to SQL-Server so apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check data for `[Last Call Back]` column in your table. Check that all data are valid for date conversion or not. I think some string are not valid to convert it into date. So you need to check it by ISDate() function. ISDDate() function will work based on your language and culture like below.

```
SET LANGUAGE british
SELECT ISDATE('2013-11-20')   /* will return 0 */

SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT ISDATE('2013-11-20')   /* will return 1 */
```

For example, If your column have format like below then it will give error

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2013-11-20', 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Your Problem is Here 
Because I seem [Last Call Back] is Varchar() datatype 
when you convert varchar datatype is date and compare with varchar then you got this error
Please  you should change Both condition in Same Datatype

```
WHERE  [Last Call Back] = (SELECT MAX(Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103))FROM Projects2)
```

Comment: That was my first thought when reading the query as well. Why on earth _convert_ a column in any format to something else, and then compare it with the _original_ column format?